# html <base> doesn't work with href to localhost

Tags: html, url, radix

My links look like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/utils/style.css" />
```

I had my website in main dir so it wasn't a problem but when I moved all my files to /dir/ I set up base tag :

```
<base href="http://localhost/dir" />
```

But it doesn't work. It works perfectly fine though if I use online URL to my website

```
<base href="http://www.my-website.com" />
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: check if you can acces the css with http://localhost/dir/utils/style.css

Comment: Could you run the following piece of JavaScript please: `alert(document.baseURI)` Then see what that says your base URI is. If that's not what you want it to be, then that's your problem. (you can run it by putting `javascript:alert(document.baseURI)` in your URL bar)

Comment: So basically problem if my urls start with '/' like <a href='/dir/a.html'> I can't set path in my base, it seems like it takes only host so I can have <base href="http://my-website.com/NonExistenceDir" /> and it still works!! Bizzare ...

Comment: My rule of thumb: “If you need to use the `base` element, then you are doing something wrong already.” // Don’t call your projects via `http://localhost/dir`, but set up a proper virtual host and local domain name for the project - then you don’t have issues like that in the first place. Plus, your setup will match the later production environment more closely, so there is also less error potential when you deploy from your dev environment to the live site.

Answer (score 4):

Dir is a directory therefore you need to add a / after it, also you don't need to use base to have clean URL's... If that's what your trying to do.

`<base href="http://localhost/dir/" />`

Comment: adding '/' at the end changes nothing.

It seems like base looks only at host and doesn't care what is after first '/' since it works even when I type

<base href="http://www.my-website.com/someImaginaryDir" />
So how can I set up href="http://localhost/dir/" ??

Comment: Have your tried using the full url for the css?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/utils/style.css" />`

Comment: how are you running localhost as flat files, ore apache, IIS ?

Comment: Well I use apache, onmy raspberry pi, I use it has a development server, but yeah I use apache

Comment: Worked for me @John Aves!

Answer (score 2):

Pawel you can use base tag as :

```
<base href="http://localhost/dir/" >
```

It should work perfectly on localhost whereas in case of live website you can use directly the root extension :

```
<base href="/dir/" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Because dir is a directory you have to finish with a trailing /

Try

```
<base href="http://localhost/dir/" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="utils/style.css" />
```

EXTRA

It may be neater to map your local host to a real url this would solve your issues.

Should be something like this in your hostfile

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       dev.my-website.com
```

Comment: the point is I don't want to change all my url so they need stay href="/utils/style.css" etc

Comment: Then it is probably best to sort yoururl, why dont you map your localhost to a url in your host file.

Comment: That would be great but I can't map url paths like 127.0.0.1/dir/ localhost2

Answer (score 0):

Pawel, answer to your comment "So basically problem if my urls start ...": Think like this and it will all make sense: If your URL:s in links are absolute, then your browser uses those URL:s *as they are* and sends them to the server, because in that case the browser has no need to transform them into absolute paths before sending them to the server. So that's the reason the browser does not care whatever (illegal or not) path you have specified as `href` in the `base` tag. (The browser already has the information it needs.)

I recommend you to use the scheme I've written below. That scheme works well for me. Note that the URL:s you specify in `<a href> <img src>` etc. should all be relative (i.e. not begin with a slash) like so: `mytoplevel-dir/mysubdir/myresource.xxx` or, if the resource is located right under the root, like so: `myresource.xxx`. Note that you should *not* (need to) go up any level(s) (`../subdir` or `../myresource.xxx`). Now, when you have made your URL:s relative, the `href` of the `base` tag starts to matter.

About making the code to suit both your local development environment and your live web server): Just use PHP to dynamically generate the path to use in the `base` tag. To do so, you may use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` and find any context path (i.e. directory that is specific for your website on your local server). This works well (I use it). Example:

```html
<?php require_once('../common/php/URL_Manager.php'); ?>
.
.
<base href="<?php echo URL_Manager::getCurrentServerAndContextPath(); ?>" />
.
.
```

My understanding is that `<base href>` shall have a fully qualified path that ends with a `/` (forward slash), whereas *relative* paths shall be used elsewhere e.g. in `<a href>`, `<img src>` and `<link href>` (for internal links that is).

**Without** `<base href>`, the browser resolves each relative path encountered by using the path as seen in its address bar, into an absolute path -- which is the path sent to the server.

**With** `<base href>`, the browser resolves each relative path encountered on that page by using the absolute path stated in the `<base href>`, into an absolute path -- which is the path sent to the server.

Note that either way the server receives only *absolute* paths.

Finally for completeness, I should mention that when you use the `base` tag like I propose above, each anchor link you may have need to be supplemented with the current path, like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo URL_Manager::getCurrentPath(); ?>#menuBookmark">
```

instead of just:

```
<a href="#menuBookmark">
```